# Add space between the last item in a scrolling list and the border of the parent

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to spacing between the last item in my list and the border of the parent container. The margin I set for the child elements seems to add space between the first element and the start of the parent container, but doesn't have the same effect on the last element and I'm not sure why. If would someone could explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    scrollSnapType: "x mandatory",
    width: "500px",
    height: "100px",
    border: "solid black 1px",
    overflow: "auto",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  },
  item: {
    scrollSnapAlign: "center",
    height: "50px",
    minWidth: "50px",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    margin: "10%"
  }
}));

export default function SimpleCollapse() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
      <div className={classes.item}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R8hH.png)
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpT8U.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Margins are for moving an element in from the wrapper, not expanding the wrapper outwards.

For a full explanation, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28682628/8062659).

---

The solution is to add a `pseudo ::after` element to the container. The idea is inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53243151/8062659) but the implementation is different.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    ...
    "&::after": {
      content: `""`,
      minWidth: "0.1px", // 0.01px will not work ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
      height: "100%"
    }
  },
  ...
}));
```

[image: Edit late-glade-tnj1d]